# How to separate spring contexts in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I have a problem configuring IntelliJ IDEA for developing spring and maven powered application.

App has two separate spring configurations for production and test purposes. In spring facet props in IDEA I created two different file sets but when configuring one of contexts IDEA shows variants for both ones in code completion. How can I deal with this?

Thanks

Aleksander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option is to create two different filesets of spring config. If the beans are defined in both the filesets, it would links the beans to both filesets. Obviously I don't think it (or any IDE) is capable of resolving if it has to use main/test filesets based on your code path. Hope they would enhance the sprint context(fileset) resolution based on the code path (source/test). But it would be difficult for the IDE as the main business logic falls in both main/test context during the flow.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA 2016.2 has checkbox: Check test files:
[image]

After check on IDEA stop complain, that test files not included in Spring Facet.
Try to play with it.